# code is not same after run merge git "git merge b_branch"

Tags: git

I have 3 branch

```
1. a_branch
2. b_branch
3. master
```

I have done changes in a branch not I want that change in `b_branch` also so I merge code when I merge branches then it's say already up to dated.

But when I see in the git site then code is not same?

```
git checkout a_branch
git merge b_branch
```

Comment: I dont understand what you need.

Comment: Have you added your changes to the index and commit them before merging? It is a good practice to do a 'git status' and 'git diff <file>' before commiting and merging, just to make sure that everything is like you want.

Comment: @CodeWizard I have commit all the files and push them on git site. changes are there. But when i merge date in master then it show me already up to date and changes are not there.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem correctly then you want to have changes of a_branch into b_branch

1. `git checkout a_branch`
2. make your changes
3. commit those changes
4. `git checkout b_branch`
5. `git merge a_branch`
6. congrats your b_branch has the changes of a branch
7. Also you can check the diff by `git diff a_branch b_branch`